# Is it possible to remove commis present in one branch, which are absent in another branch?

Tags: git, merge, bitbucket, git-merge

I am using Git (Bitbucket) have one master branch and two release branches like below;

```
master
  '--release/1.0
       '--release/2.0
```

In an ideal situation, all commits in release/1.0 will be present in `release/2.0` and `master`. Also, all commits in `release/2.0` is present in `master`.

Due to some reasons, here are some extra commits present in master, making it ahead of `release/2.0`. I want to sync `release/2.0` with `master`, that extra commits present in master which are not present in `release/2.0` should be removed. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean you just added commits in `master` (as opposed to having them interlaced somewhere done the tree), you could just `reset` the `master` branch:

```
# switch to master
$ git checkout master

# reset it to release/2.0
$ git reset --hard release/2.0
```